# Grammatical structure: She was furious and with reason

Tags: conjunctions

> She was furious and with reason.

Can you explain the grammatical anatomy of the sentence above, in particular about the need for the use of and?

To me, the sentence appears to be divided into these two parts: She was furious.; and she was furious with reason. Essentially, the sentence can be shortened to "she was furious with reason," right? Why and for what effect is the conjunction "and" used?

Comment: "And with reason" is best analysed as a verbless clause. In full it would be "and she was furious with reason."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of 'and', although seemingly unnecessary, adds emphasis. Redundancy can add even more: She was furious, and was furious with reason.

Answer (score 0):

She was furious with reason.

Here, 'with reason' means 'justifiably'. In this sentence, the word *'reason'* has not been emphasized.

But if you want to put emphasis on *'reason'*, you can write :

> She was furious and with reason.

( = She was furious, and *she was furious* with reason.)

This is *repetition* for the sake of *emphasis*.